# Android Phone App not displayed on customized freescale's I.MX6 SabseSD board

Tags: android

I have compiled android jelly bean(4.2.2) for i.Mx6q sabre SD reference board . In my compiled image phone app is not displayed on the tablet but Phone.apk is present inside `/out/../system/app/` directory. Can anyone tell me what modification I need to do in source code, So that phone App appears on display.